# Laravel Query DB Get Results from 2 Users with ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I work on an Message System and i want Query the conversation between 2 Users. I cant use Controller now, soo i must try it on this way.

I want display the Results for example `Title` between my User ID `Auth::user` and the Senders ID.

Where "to" is my ID= `Auth::user` : `->where('to',`

How can i change this Code, because with my Code i see all Messages from me and not only between my ID and the Other part ID:

```
<?php $subjects = DB::table('messages')->where('to', '=', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('title'); echo $subject; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second where clause, just chain them like this

```
<?php $subjects = DB::table('messages')->where('to', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('from', '=', $senders_id)->pluck('title'); echo $subject; ?>
```

Check documentation for more information about query building
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses